# Create Restrict Area on /Map

Tags: ros, laser, ros-kinetic, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to create restriction area for path planning. Robot mustn't go restriction area that user's indicated. In additional map mustn't include obstacle that not sensor's seems. Is it possible ? Which way i follow if it's possible ?

Thanks for helping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304445/create-restrict-area-on-/map/) by [Onur](https://answers.ros.org/users/36628/onur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote the code which can restricted area. The package link as a following.
[RestrictAreaPlugin](https://github.com/honorde/RestrictAreaPlugin),
[And Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJn96LBu2l4)

---

Originally posted by [Onur](https://answers.ros.org/users/36628/onur/) with karma: 38 on 2018-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1